# calculating distance in consecutive records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on an application which keeps track of refuels.
Every record stores data about a visit at the gasstation.
I've decided to store as little information in the database as possible and calculate things in the controller.

This is my model:

```
public class Refuel
{
    #region Properties

        public int id { get; set; }
        public int mileage { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> volume { get; set; }
        public Nullable<double> price { get; set; }

        public Nullable<int> imageId { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> gasstationId { get; set; }

        public virtual Gasstation Gasstation { get; set; }
        public virtual Image Image { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Methods

        public int distance { get; set; }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "€ {0:0.00}")]
        public Nullable<double> totalPrice
        {
            get
            {
                return volume * price;
            }
        }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
        public Nullable<double> consumption
        {
            get
            {
                if (distance > 0)
                    return volume / distance * 100;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0}")]
        public Nullable<double> consumption2
        {
            get
            {
                if (distance > 0)
                    return distance / volume;
                else
                    return 0;
            }
        }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
        public Nullable<double> mileageLeft
        {
            get 
            {
                return volumeLeft * consumption2;
            }
        }

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")]
        public Nullable<double> volumeLeft
        {
            get
            {
                double? d = 45 - volume;
                return d;
            }
        }

    #endregion
}
```

As you can see I don't do anything with the distance here.
I calculate the distance in the details page of one specific record.

What I want to do now is make a summary on the index page summing the distance and calculate the average consumption.
This is all relative to the distance, but this is an empty field at that point.

I've got the same problem with showing a list of all records on the index page.
The distance and consumption columns are empty.

What would be the best way to get the distance filled at that point?
Or would it be better to store the distance in the database after all?

This is my index function:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "asc" : "";

        List<Refuel> rf = db.Refuels.ToList();
        var refuels = from t in db.Refuels select t;

        switch (sortOrder)
        {
            case "asc":
                refuels = refuels.OrderBy(q => q.mileage);
                break;
            default:
                refuels = refuels.OrderByDescending(q => q.mileage);
                break;
        }

        // statistieken
        ViewBag.count = rf.Count();
        ViewBag.distance = rf.Sum(q => q.distance);
        ViewBag.volume = rf.Sum(q => q.volume);
        ViewBag.consumption = String.Format("{0:0.0}", rf.Where(q => q.consumption > 0).Average(q => q.consumption));
        ViewBag.consumption2 = String.Format("{0:0.0}", rf.Where(q => q.consumption2 > 0).Average(q => q.consumption2));
        ViewBag.cost = String.Format("{0:c2}", rf.Sum(q => q.totalPrice));

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
        return View(refuels.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Managed to fix the summary part, of course I could just use the last and first mileage to get the total distance driven:

```
ViewBag.count = tb.Count();
ViewBag.distance = tb.Last().mileage - tb.First().mileage;
ViewBag.volume = tb.Sum(q => q.volume);
ViewBag.consumption = String.Format("{0:0.0}", ViewBag.volume / ViewBag.distance * 100);
ViewBag.consumption2 = String.Format("{0:0.0}", ViewBag.distance / ViewBag.volume);
ViewBag.cost = String.Format("{0:c2}", tb.Sum(q => q.totalPrice));
```

All I need to do now is display the distance per record in the index table.
This is the loop in my index.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink(Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.mileage).ToString(), "Details", new { id = item.id })
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.date)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.distance)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.volume)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.consumption)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.totalPrice)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Gasstation.fullname)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: What is the distance -- the distance traveled since the refuel?  Maybe the distance you can go on the remaining gas?

Comment: FYI `Nullable<double>` can be replaced by `double?`

Comment: @Hogan You are right about the distance. It's distance traveled since last refuel.

Comment: From what you have posted there is no calculation being done on the `distance` variable.  To calculate that value you have to loop through each record, which sounds costly compared to simply storing that value in the database.  Each record will depend on the previous one all the way back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whatever you are doing in the detail page of the single record to calculate the distance have to be done in this case also. If you think that operation is costlier than storing the distance field in database - you got the answer.

Comment: I'll go for this answer after all. Saves me a lot of calculations on different spots if I just save the last mileage in every new record. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it right in the view itself. Just run a for loop on the collection to display your records and get the last refuel mileage as either i+1 or i-1 (based on ViewBag.CurrentSort) and just do the math right there.

**EDIT**
Haven't tested this but here's what it would look like:

You have to return an extra record to calculate the distance on the first or last record in the collection so you would have to change your ToPagedList method to accept the sort order and return either an extra item before or after the records you want to display.

Then your for loop would look something like:

```
@{
    bool asc = ((string)ViewBag.CurrentSort).ToLower() == "asc";
    int i = 0;
    int records = Model.Count;

    //If sort is asc you want to skip the first record (the extra record you returned to do the calculation), else you want to stop before you get to the extra row at the end of the collection
    if (asc) i += 1;
    else records -= 1;

for (i; i<records; i++)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink(Model[i].mileage.ToString(), "Details", new { id = Model[i].id })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].date)
    </td>
    <td>
        @if (asc) {
        @Html.Display(Model[i].mileage - Model[i - 1].mileage)
        }
        else {
           @Html.Display(Model[i].mileage - Model[i + 1].mileage)
        }
etc...
```

That being said, this feels like a lot of work for what should be a pretty basic function. And you're starting to get away from one of the main points of MVC which is the separation of your business logic from your views.

It really looks as though your permanent solution should be to store the distance in the database. When you add a new record to your refuel table you should get the previous one first and calculate the distance to include when you add the new record. All you're adding is one additional call to get a single record and database operations are cheap enough where you should only see a difference on an extremely large scale. But even then, all this work above is going to be done on the server anyway and repeating it every time is likely much more expensive.

Comment: The distance I'm mentioning is the distance traveled on one gas tank. I need this distance to calculate consumption.

Comment: Can you give me some pointers on how to achieve this? I'm not sure how to get the value from i-1 or i+1 in a for loop..

Comment: I'm using a foreach loop in my view by the way, this doesn't have an index, see original post for index.cshtml

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor in your model and set distance to 0, then worry about filling it later.